# Transaction management with JPA: how to perform a rollback if an error occurs at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Supposing that I've a **DAO** defined as follows:

```
@Local(MyEntityDAO.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Stateless
public class MyEntityDAO {

    public MyEntity create(MyEntity entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    // Etc. [...]

}
```

All methods throw **JPA standard exceptions**.
Now, I'd like to setup data **transactions** in order to manage rollbacks if an occurs at runtime.

A first approach that I found is to inject an `UserTransaction` together with a DAO instance, as follows:

```
@ManagedBean    
class myBean() {

    @Inject myEntityDAO myEntityDAO;
    @Resource UserTransaction userTransaction;

    void doSomething() {
        try {
            // userTransaction.begin();
            MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity("sample-data");
            myEntityDAO.create(myEntity);
            userTransaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            userTransaction.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

1. Is the solution above right?
2. Is it possible to automatically manage transactions just by annotating an **EJB** and using as said **JPA standard exceptions**?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Any runtime exceptions that are thrown from an EJB method call automatically cause transaction rollback. You only need:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEntityDAO {

    public MyEntity create(MyEntity entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    // Etc. [...]

}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean    
class myBean() {

    @Inject MyEntityDAO myEntityDAO;

    void doSomething() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity("sample-data");
        myEntityDAO.create(myEntity);
    }

}
```

You just need to ensure that each operation that you need to be atomic is implemented in the DAO.

Any JPA exception that is thrown will be wrapped in a [javax.ejb.EJBException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBException.html) which you would need to deal with at the UI somehow.